# android screen settings for emulator and phone

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am working on application for my phone (Samsung Galaxy i8150 W).Which settings should I use for true screen. My phone has 3.7 inch. screen 480x800px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly: "Start" your AVD, after that "Launch Options" will appear, then toggle checkbox "Scale display to real size", set up needed settings, and finally "Launch" your AVD.

Comment: I found the problem.I was working normal theme on eclipse but launch NOlittleBar :)